# recursive JSON java

Tags: java, json, spring, web, jackson

When starting the server, I get stuck.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwtxo.png)

Apparently it's a matter of models, but it's not clear what.

Connection to the base via JPA.

User

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "User")
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, /*cascade = CascadeType.ALL,*/ 
targetEntity = Role.class)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
private Set<Role> roles;

public User() {
}

public User(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public User(String name, String surname, String password, Set<Role> roles) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;

}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPass() {
    return password;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
            //", role='" + roles.toString() + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<Role> roleList = new HashSet<>();
    roleList.addAll(roles);
    return roleList;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "roleName", length = 20, nullable = false)
private String roleName;

//private String role;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, /*mappedBy = "roles",*/ targetEntity = 
User.class)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
private List<User> users;

public Role() {
}

public Role(String roleName) {
    this.roleName = roleName;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Collection<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}


public String getRoleName() {
    return roleName;
}

public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
    this.roleName = roleName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Role with id " + id + " and name " + roleName;
}

public String getAuthority() {
    return getRoleName();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Role role = (Role) o;
    return Objects.equals(roleName, role.roleName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(roleName);
}
```

}

I thought it was a cascade and FetchType. But everything seems to be correct.

I tried using toString to contact from the User to the Role, and vice versa. Also without result. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the annotation @JsonIgnore above the getter of one of the two class, let me explain:
when you call a user object it uses a role object, the called role object contains a user object, so it uses another user object and as you have an infinite loop user -> role -> user -> role -> user -> role .....
@JsonIgnore of the jackson api does when you call a user object, it will get it without a role, the call to the role will be done when you use the getRole ().
Hope this would be helpfull

Comment: On the getter, or on the field. I recommend adding `@JsonIgnore` on the `users` field in the `Role` class, because you probably don't want a role to list all the users it contains.

Comment: would you like to accept my answer if it answers your question